Transform of a differential operator to get a constant coefficient equation and how to set up the characteristic equation?
Say I have a Sturm-Liouville ODE:
$$\Big(x y(x)'\Big)' + \lambda y(x)  = 0$$
And I want to solve this problem by subbing in: $x\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{d}{du}$ which makes the problem:
$$\tag{1}\frac{d^2 y(x)}{du^2} - \lambda y(x) = 0$$
. We obtain a constant coefficient ODE in this form, however $y(x)$ in our equation so if I were to sub in $y(x) = e^{r x}$ to get our characteristic equation, I wouldn't be able to differentiate $e^{r x}$ wrt u without subbing $x\frac{d}{dx}$ back in and then we're back to square one.

My assumption is that if $x\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{d}{du}$, then we also have the relationship that:
$$\tag{2} y(x) = g(u)$$
though I don't know if that's correct or not. If it is, I could use chain rule and go from there to create an ODE and solve for $u(x)$, and then I think I know where to go from there. Or is there a different process altogether for how to do this?
